# Xcode 10.0 user search path for classes(deprecated)

Tags: ios, xcode10

Having problems importing diff class, in Xcode 10. This doesn't occur in their previews version. Any Suggestion to fix this?

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Xcode [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html) you have to use include syntax.

> The legacy header map that was generated when the Always Search User
>   Paths (ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS) setting was YES is not supported by
>   the new build system. Instead, set ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS to NO and
>   migrate to using modern header include syntax. Add any needed header
>   files that are in the project repository to the Xcode project to
>   ensure they are available for use in #include (via the project wide
>   header map). Use quote-style include ("foo.h") for project headers,
>   and reserve angle-bracket include () for system headers.

For example:

```
#import <SystemFile/SystermFile.h>
#import "ProjectFile.h"
```

[image: RN]

Comment: ahh i see (ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS) is not supported by the new build system? for #import "foo.h", when its in path>>Resources>>foo.h and when i import for example foo.h in other class it doesn't suggest the header file for ("foo.h") even in #include

Comment: @dxMiguel Yes, as per release notes it's not supported.

Comment: what is the alternative? how to import files now which are in different groups?

Comment: You're a life-saver! I never would have guessed this.